# convert UIImage to TLPHAsset and inset into selectedAssets array

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, collectionview

i am using `TLPhotoPicker` for select multiple image and video and everything works fine expect one thing after selecting images from picker its stored in an array which has type `TLPHAsset`

```
var selectedAssets = [TLPHAsset]()
```

and after store all images in this array i am populating CollectionView from this array till then every thing works fine.

Now i am using PhotoEditor for edit image

https://github.com/eventtus/photo-editor

so when i on didSelect of collectionview i am getting image and i pass that image to PhotoEditor and then after editing photo on delegate Method i get edited image as UIImage.

Now i want to inset that edited image to selectedAssets array but when i tried to insert i got below error

```
self.selectedAssets.insert(image, at: 0) //Cannot convert value of type 'UIImage' to expected argument type 'TLPHAsset'
```

so can anyone please tell me how to solve this is there any way to convert `UIImage` to `TLPHAsset`

Comment: This could be the solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52941270/2227743